livewire file upload not working on cpanel shared hosting but working on localhost
This code seems to be uploading files very well in localhost livewire but on uploading the code to cpanel, file upload not working, it seems even the livewire-tmp folder is not created
/**
* Add product and the product variation
*/
public function createProductWithVariations()
{
$this->validate();
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {

        $product = $this->createProduct();
        $this->saveProductTags($product);

        //create product variation for the created product
        $productVariation = ProductVariation::create([
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'variation_id' => $this->variation_id,
            'price' => $this->price,
        ]);

        //save product variation images
        foreach ($this->images as $image) {
            // Generate a unique name for the image
            $name = time() . '-' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = $image->storeAs('product_variation_images', $name, 'public');

            // Store the image path in the database
            ProductVariationImage::create([
                'product_variation_id' => $productVariation->id,
                'image_url' => $path,
            ]);
        }


        DB::commit();
        $this->reset(['category_id', 'name', 'description', 'variation_id', 'price', 'images']);
        $this->alert('success', 'Product created successfully');
        $this->dispatch('productCreated');

    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        dd($exception->getMessage());
        DB::rollBack();
        $this->alert('error', $exception->getMessage());
    }
}


the problem might be storage might not have been linked. Try deleting public>storage folder and then run php artisan storage:link command
